# Is Titanium appcelerator worth it for developing a complex application on ipad, iphone and android?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Is Titanium appcelerator worth it for developing a complex application on ipad, iphone and android? Which can support charts, grids, widgets and schedule control?

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Seyal, Titanium Appcelerator support all the native controls(upto iPhone 4). I think charts, grids, widgets and schedule controls are only third party controls. It is very difficult to use those controls in Titanium. You have an option to use the [webview](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView). You need to draw graphs using html and need to load it using the webview. But you can't use it for other purposes like, creating grid or for using other controls

You have another choice to use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), which is a cross-platfrom, which supports all your requirement(plugins are available for your requirement).

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't support all the native features of each device.
For example, user interface in Android would need a widget. No support for that in Appcelerator, as it's specific to Android.

Comment: What do you mean by "user interface"? Are you talking about dashboard widgets? Because you'd be right, Titanium doesn't support those AFAIK. But if you're suggesting Titanium doesn't support ANY UI for Android, then I'd say you're misinformed.

Comment: Down-voted for being very misleading, at best. Belligerent and misinformed at worst. Edit and I'll gladly reverse my vote.